# SQL owner chaining

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Basically I have a front end application called AdminProgram. In SQL Server I have a role called AdminProgramUsers.

Now this role has permissions to various SPs and the like but, crucially, there is no select permission on any table. Everything they see or modify is done through SPs.

Now I've just written a new SP for them. I have had no choice but to use dynamic SQL, that is constructing the actual SQL query in a String variable called @FinalQuery and then running EXECUTE @FinalQuery.

Now initially I was getting a lot of user doesn't have access to the tables, needed to either grant SELECTs to the columns in question, but that solution won't work due to internal politics.

The other thing I seem to understand is that I need to use `EXECUTE AS` somehow. I have Googled, but I'm struggling to get this right.

And to pre-emptively answer a couple of questions, there is no option but to use dynamic SQL in this SP much to my displeasure, we're talking about SQL Server 2005 and there will be no way of signing any SPs with certificates (mainly as the DBA will flip a nut at the prospect of anything complicated).

So... I think the answer lies somewhere in EXECUTE AS with ownership chaining... but I need to know how to do it... assuming that the role available is AdminProgramUsers...

The current solution I have is:

```
CREATE SP MySp AS
DECLARE @FinalTable (columns)

DECLARE @FinalQuery
SET @FinalQuery = "EXECUTE AS CALLER
SELECT blah blah"

INSERT  @FinalTable 
EXECUTE (@QueryString) AS user ='AdminProgramUsers'
```

Do some more processing on @FinalTable

```
Select * from @FinalTable
```

The error I get is:

> Unexpected Error in My Sp
>   Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "AdminProgramUsers" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an excerpt from [ms documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) about `execute` on sql server 2005:

> The user or login name specified in AS { LOGIN | USER } = ' name '
>   must exist as a principal in sys.database_principals or
>   sys.server_principals, respectively, or the statement will fail.
>   Additionally, IMPERSONATE permissions must be granted on the
>   principal. Unless the caller is the database owner or is a member of
>   the sysadmin fixed server role, the principal must exist even when the
>   user is accessing the database or instance of SQL Server through a
>   Windows group membership.

in your code you feed the `execute` a role but a user or login is expected instead.

the above text is not very clear if you don't read this:

> LOGIN
>
> Specifies the context to be impersonated is a login. The scope
>   of impersonation is the server.
>
> USER
>
> Specifies the context to be
>   impersonated is a user in the current database.  The scope of
>   impersonation is restricted to the current database.  A context switch
>   to a database user does not inherit the server-level permissions of
>   that user.

you can specify a user or a login as impersonation context; [a role is neither a login nor a user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).